# what's the errors for my "check if value strings equal dictionary exercise"?

Tags: python, dictionary

## Here's the question of my exercise:

Write a function called is_1_to_1 that accepts a dictionary whose keys and values are strings as its
parameter and returns True if no two keys map to the same value.

and I got this:

```
def is_1_to_1(dic):
for value_1 in dic.values():
    for value_2 in dic.values():
        check_list = []
        if value_2 == value_1 :
            check_list.append(value_2)
        else:
            pass

if check_list != dic:
    return (f"Dictionary: {dict.items(dic)} does not have unique entries.")

else:
    return (f"DIctionary: {dict.items(dic)} does have unique entries.")

dic_1 = {"Marty": "206-9024", "Hawking": "123-4567",
"Smith": "949-0504", "Newton": "123-4567"}

dic_2 = {"Marty": "206-9024", "Hawking": "555-1234",
"Smith": "949-0504", "Newton": "123-4567"}

print(is_1_to_1(dic_1))

print(is_1_to_1(dic_2))
```

it return:

```
Dictionary: dict_items([('Marty', '206-9024'), ('Hawking', '123-4567'), ('Smith', '949-0504'), ('Newton', '123-4567')]) does not have unique entries.
Dictionary: dict_items([('Marty', '206-9024'), ('Hawking', '555-1234'), ('Smith', '949-0504'), ('Newton', '123-4567')]) does not have unique entries.
```

Comment: What is your expected output for both dictionaries?

Comment: {"Marty": "206-9024", "Hawking": "123-4567",
 "Smith": "949-0504", "Newton": "123-4567"}
but for the following dictionary your function should return True because each key maps to a unique value:
{"Marty": "206-9024", "Hawking": "555-1234",
 "Smith": "949-0504", "Newton": "123-4567"}
The empty dictionary is considered 1-to-1 and returns True.

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment). It will be more readable and more people will see it - so more people can help you.

Comment: in question you have `...and returns True` but you return strings.

Comment: `else: pass` is useless - you don't have to use `else` if you don't have code for this part.

Comment: cheking `check_list != dic` is useless it will never be the same. Better check if `check_list` is not empty - `if not check_list:` . But you have different problem - you create `check_list` inside `for`-loop so it replace previous content with new empty list - you should create it before all `for`-loops. But there is bigger mistakes - you compare the same elements in dict - like `dict["Marry"] == dict["Marry"]` and this will always give wrong result. You should check values only `if key1 != key2`

Answer (score 0):

You have few mistakes.

1. comparing `check_list != dic` is useless because it will always gives `True`. You should rather check if `check_list` is empty `if not check_list:`
2. you create `check_list` inside `for`-loops so it replace it with new empty list and you may get empty list if last elements are different.
3. you compare the same values - like `dict["Marry"] == dict["Marry"]` - so you always get value in `check_list`. You should first check `key1 != key2`
4. in question you have `... and return True` but you always return strings.

---

Because `not check_list` gives `True` or `False` so it can be reduced to     return (not check_list)`

```
def is_1_to_1(dic):
    check_list = []
    
    for key1, val1 in dic.items():
        for key2, val2 in dic.items():
            if key1 != key2 and val1 == val2 :
                check_list.append(val2)

    #if not check_list:  # check if empty
    #    return True
    #else:
    #    return False

    # shorter
    return (not check_list)

# --- main ---

dic_1 = {
    "Marty": "206-9024",
    "Hawking": "123-4567",
    "Smith": "949-0504",
    "Newton": "123-4567",
}

dic_2 = {
    "Marty": "206-9024",
    "Hawking": "555-1234",
    "Smith": "949-0504",
    "Newton": "123-4567",
}

print(is_1_to_1(dic_1))
print(is_1_to_1(dic_2))
```

---

You could also reduce it to

```
def is_1_to_1(dic):
    for key1, val1 in dic.items():
        for key2, val2 in dic.items():
            if key1 != key2 and val1 == val2 :
                return False  # exit on first matching element

    # after checking all elements
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

There are usually many different ways to solve a problem. A quick solution for this could be as simple as:

```
def is_1_to_1(dic):
    values = dic.values()
    return len(values) == len(set(values))
```

A Python `set` only consists of unique values. So if the lengths differ, it means the original set of dict values includes duplicates.

As a side note, your code cannot succeed because of the comparison:

```
if check_list != dic:
```

As you have coded it, `check_list` is an array, and `dic` is a dict. So they  will never truly match, and this comparison will always be a True. Plus, with the logic you use, cycling through the list of dict values twice, you will end up with `check_list` simply being the same as `dic.values()`.

Comment: I also just noticed that you reset check_list = [] in every loop, so it really doesn't hold any useful information. You definitely need to reconsider your logic.